# Strategies for managing database schema in an application using an XML based modelling

Tags: java, mysql, xml, hibernate

The application I'm working on currently uses a MySQL database. We are planning to change the architecture of the application to process data in an XML format. So the object model for the application will be driven by the XML schema. Now we can use tools such as JAXB to do XML parsing and create an object structure in memory.
However the main problems I see are:-

1. How to map the object structure into a relational database. We could use Hibernate here.
2. Another problem is that the XML schema will change on a regular basis, and we need to support previous versions of the schema.

I'm not sure of the best way to handle item 2, as the database schema could very easily start to get bloated with many tables as the number of schema versions increase.

So my main question is, what are the best strategies to manage such version changes, both from an object modelling perspective, and database schema perspective?

Comment: Yes. The change in architecture is evolutionary, so we need to support the existing processes. Are you thinking we should be using an XML or object based database?

Comment: Possibly - or maybe something like Postgres that supports inheritance in the db schema definition. If the changes to the schema were relatively small and mainly additive in nature, it _may_ offer some help. I have to say that I have precisely NO experience of using Postgres in this way though.

Comment: You were not specific on the various changes that would take place on the entities. Would the changes be relational changes or just new properties (columns)? Also where does the XML come from? Do you read it from a web service so for different versions of the schema you are going to have a different web service? I am asking because JAXB will need a point of reference concerning the classes it will use to map your XML to.

Comment: We could have both structural (relational) changes, and also changes in properties of the entities. The XML comes into the system in the form of HTTP messages. We will have a message decoder component that parses the XML message and validates against a schema. Several versions of the messages will need to be supported

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be:

Keep enriching your schema but make sure it is backward compatible with previous schemas so that JAXB can parse and map the oldest and newest schema based XML into your objects. This would mean changes to your database schema with the same again target to have a schema which is compatible to older entities you want to map; also the schema namespaces etc should be the same for all versions for JAXB to work. I suppose you are going to have a lot of nullable columns etc. It is future risky but it could work if done right.

Oh now I see that you edited your comment and gave me more information so:

Since the schema changes constantly I would suggest skipping JAXB. JAXB is not made for these kind of constant changes. Smooks(Install JBoss Tools plugins in your Eclipse) is. It will allow you to define a different mapping definition for each different version of schema based XML to your Hibernate entity classes. So in this way you will maintain the Smooks mappings, Hibernate entity classes and database schema. Concerning the database schema there are ways to make it evolutionary with no structural changes but you would have to sacrifice referential integrity...I wouldnt

I suppose there are many solutions to your problem

Comment: Sorry, my wording was slightly misleading. There will be many versions of the XML schema. So the problem is really how to cope with the many versions of the schema, and the effect on the database.
Thanks for the link to Smooks, not used that before.

Comment: Since you are going to have a component validating the XML against it's schema it means you will be able to distinguish which Smooks mapping definition to use in order to map the XML of the specific schema to to your Hibernate objects. The database must be updated structurally though to be able to make happy all the schemas and this means the Hibernate classes will also be affected structurally. This means downtime of course. This makes it even clearer to avoid JAXB because you are going to have a new set of classes for each schema which means also more class definitions to load for the VM.

Answer (score 0):

The evolving nature of the XML schema means that using JAXB isn't scalable, as it would mean statically generating a new batch of classes every time the schema changed. All previous versions of the schema must be supported by the system.

I've decided to use [XSOM](http://xsom.java.net/) to parse the XML schema. This means that the correct schema version can be selected and processed dynamically at run-time. So we can build a generic way of parsing schemas and instantiating appropriate classes.